# BadTokenException Unable to add Window Spinner in PopUpWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-windowmanager

I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but I'm not able to transfer the answers to my problem (or I didn't find THE answer I need...)

In my menu on actionBar (in onOptionsItemSelected) I open a popupWindow for user settings. Checkbox and RadioButtons work fine, but if I tab on the Spinner, there will be a FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@42766f00 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

This is the code in the `onOptionsItemSelected` Method:

```
LayoutInflater inflaterSettings = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final LinearLayout llSettings = (LinearLayout) inflaterSettings.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_menu_settings_popup, null);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) llSettings .findViewById(R.id.spinner_action_settings_intervall_values);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_settings_intervall_values, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){ TODO}
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { // TODO }
});
PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(context);
popUp.setContentView(llSettings);
llSettings.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        popUp.showAtLocation(llSettings, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        width = (int) (width * 0.9);
        height = (int) (height * 0.9);
        popUp.update(width, height);
    }
});
```

My actionbar_menu_settings_popup.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_action_settings_intervall_values"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/action_settings_intervall_values" />
```

and in string.xml:

```
<string-array name="action_settings_intervall_values">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>45</item>
    <item>60</item>
    <item>120</item>
    <item>180</item>
</string-array>
```

**EDIT**

Made a Log in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
Log.i("MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems", "context: " + context);
Log.i("MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems", "getApplicationContext: " + getApplicationContext());
Log.i("MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems", "this: " + this);
```

result:

```
06-21 10:40:58.185: I/MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems(14463): context: de.xy.app.activities.MainActivity@42743818
06-21 10:40:58.185: I/MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems(14463): getApplicationContext: android.app.Application@42741d48
06-21 10:40:58.185: I/MainActivity#onCreateOptionsItems(14463): this: de.xy.app.activities.MainActivity@42743818
```

Comment: Where are you assigning context?

Comment: in `onCreate` I made `context = this;`

Comment: your popup window is not attached with the window manager.

Comment: and how to do this? the popup is shown correct....

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_settings_intervall_values, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

To

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.action_settings_intervall_values, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

This occurs mostly because of bad context reference.

Comment: You need to pass proper context. Where you pass Context (this/context) ..replace this->context or vice-versa . I think the problem will solve.

Comment: tested all versions. Loged the different options for debugging, look at the edit part. Don't misunderstand me: I know the wrong context could be a problem, but I don't know if it is here. Don't know, what I could do..